# how to save logged in user id automatically in another table in c# win forms?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table that have many properties, one of them is `UserId` like:

```
public class Note
{
    //Other property

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    //Other property
}
```

Now  when the user logged in successfully the the dashboard is displayed, User can click on button to add notes. So when the user add notes, I want to save user id automatically in notes column in `SqlServer` to know which user has added the notes.

This application is c# desktop application. As, I'm beginner in c#, I got problem to save `UserId`.

Comment: It is impossible to write an answer for this, please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you must add flag in your table with type bit for understand user is login or not 
like this

```
if(success)
{
  //when logged in successfully the flag must be Update from 0 to 1 

}
```

and you can use trigger for create change in another tables in your database

I hope it help you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you also create another table for event handling; else you will only have the last user that edited the note. Else why it’s not saving, we would need debugging data and code.